# Wordpress некорректно загружает медиа (изображения)

Tags: wordpress

При добавлении изображений в медиабиблиотеку Wordpress некоторые изображения отображаются некорректно. В данном случае 4 изображения созданных в фотошопе. Менял разрешение, менял расширение, ничего не изменяется. При этом, самое первое созданное изображение отобразилось *(№6)*. Также занимательно что они открываются во встроенном редакторе wordpress (правда проходит много времени до окончательной прогрузки). При помещении на страницу также работают некорректно.

[image: Со 2 по 5 изображение]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось довольно банальным. Все дело было в том, что названия изображений были написаны на кириллице. После переименования все стало работать.